# How to write an "OR" within a Linq to Sql .Where()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, where-clause

I want to get all records WHERE (s.override == 1 OR (s.override == 2 AND s.approved == 1))

How can I do that using the .Where `x.subcontracts.Where(s ==> ??)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use standard C# binary operators:

```
x.subcontracts
  .Where(s => s.override == 1 || (s.override == 2 && s.approved == 1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the where clause you need:

```
x.subcontracts.Where(s => (s.override == 1) || (s.override == 2 && s.approved == 1))
```